Clover vault card error : 503 No extended information provided
I am integrating Clover's Vault Card feature using the browser-based Clover Connector to generate tokens for future payments. Despite implementing the required functionality, I am encountering an issue where the VaultCard API call consistently fails with a "503" error and the message "No extended information provided."
Question
There is any settings or configurations that i need to enable for vault card token or request to enable it from Clover support to get the VaultCard API working?
Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?
Code Example
return {
    create: function(cloverConnector, connectionListener) {
        var onVaultCardResponse = function(response) {
            if (response.success) {
                const vaultedCard = response.getCard();
                console.log("#");
                console.log("# Vault Card Successful.");
                console.log("#");
                console.log("# Token:           " + vaultedCard.getToken());
                console.log("# Cardholder Name: " + vaultedCard.getCardholderName());
                console.log("# Card First 6:    " + vaultedCard.getFirst6());
                console.log("# Card Last 4:     " + vaultedCard.getLast4());
                console.log("# Card Expiration: " + vaultedCard.getExpirationDate());
                console.log("#");
            } else {
                console.log("Error message in vaultCard", response);
                console.log("!");
                console.log("! Vault Card Failed");
                console.log("!");
                console.error("Reason:", response.reason);
                console.error("Message:", response.message);
            }
            MenuLauncher.launchMenu();
        };

        return {
            run: function () {
                connectionListener.onVaultCardResponse = onVaultCardResponse;
                cloverConnector.vaultCard(clover.CardEntryMethods.ALL);
            }
        };
    }
};

Error Message
VaultCardResponse {  
  success: false,  
  result: 'FAIL',  
  reason: '503, ',  
  message: 'No extended information provided.',  
  card: undefined  
}  
Vault Card Failed!  

Reason: 503,  
Message: No extended information provided.  

Note: I'm using the Sandbox environment for testing vault card feature.
